# Linking numbers.

Tags: homotopy-theory

I would just like to check if my way of proving the following statement is correct.

For $f:\mathbb S^1\to \mathbb R^2$ \ $P$ [here $P \in \mathbb R^2$] one defines the linking number as it follows:

$Um(f,P):=deg$ $(z\to \frac {f(z)-P}{||f(z)-P||})$

The claim is next:

For a fixed point $P \in \mathbb R^2$,

$f_0,f_1:\mathbb S^1\to \mathbb R^2$ \ $P$ are homotopic iff $Um(f_0,P)=Um(f_1,P)$.

My idea of proof is that $f_0,f_1$ are homotopic iff there exists a homotopy $f_t$ $0\leq t\leq 1$ between them iff $\frac {f_t(z)-P}{||f_t(z)-P||}$ is a homotopy between $\frac {f_0(z)-P}{||f_0(z)-P||}$  and $\frac {f_1(z)-P}{||f_1(z)-P||}$ iff $Um(f_0,P)=Um(f_1,P)$

My first question is if the last homotopy is indeed a homotopy and my second question is, if so, what can guarantee that $P \notin im(\frac {f_t(z)-P}{||f_t(z)-P||})$  for any such $t$?

Comment: I think winding number is a better term. Linking refers to two loops in 3 space.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus My professor introduced later a notion of winding number throughout linking numbers which is why I didn't want to make more confusion, but do you have any idea for the last part?